# How can I upgrade my Windows 10 running in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10-upgrade

The VM is based off of a Windows 10 .iso file and inputted the product key and called Microsoft for them to override so I could use the same key for the VM Windows 10.

But I am not getting in Windows Update of Settings, "Your machine is ready to upgrade to Windows 11..."

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you confirmed that [Windows 11 is supported](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11-specifications?ocid=smc_marvel_ups_support_movetowin11&r=1) on your VM?

Comment: Did you provide enough memory (4 GB minimum) to the VM?   Did you set up TPM in the VM?  Check if Virtual Box can do this.

Comment: Run WhyNotWin11 from github to see what is missing.

Comment: I allocated over 8GB @John, I have to turn off Windows 11 capability checks, and how do I do that?

Comment: Try   https://www.whynotwin11.com/    Try this for TMP   https://pureinfotech.com/virtualbox-7-tpm-secure-boot-windows-11/